# Use different Featured Image responsively on mobile with Divi on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, image, mobile, srcset

We are trying to find a way to be able to use a separate mobile Featured Image in Divi. Specifically a squared featured image, where our desktop featured image is 1200x630, more rectangular.

There are plugins that do this, such as this one: https://wordpress.org/plugins/mobile-featured-image/ <-- but it encounters the issue that Divi does not yet make use of the 'srcset' attribute added to Wordpress in WP v4.4 a couple years back.

Is there a way around this srcset limitation? Maybe another plugin that would allow us to choose a separate featured image for mobile (not simply a smaller one in the same ratio/dimensions, but a totally different image, like the Mobile Featured Image plugin above, but without the use of srcset)?

Or is there a known way to implement srcset into a theme, maybe a tutorial of some sort?

Thanks for any and all help, we've been beating our heads against the desk on this one for about a week now  :)

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution, which I am considering, is to copy the section and then give that section a different image.

Once this is complete, use the "disable" feature (simply open the setting cog on your target and in the search type "disable")

Then, set which devices you would like that target to be loaded on.

Example:

row/module with full HD image for desktop
Disable:
mobile
tablet

row/module with mobile optimized image
Disable:
Desktop
tablet

I've use this functionality for design flow when buttons won't appear correctly or when stacking columns results in bad rows between devices with great success. Haven't yet tried this for images and not sure how this will actually work with load times and page size.

Worth a try, as it's a simple thing to do- and you can run google speed test before the edit and after the edit to see the actual net effect on the page performance.

For an example, you can navigate to my website:
NYChealing.com/about

notice, that the desktop version shows the information columns as alternating ROWS, but that on mobile, they display as duplicate styled ROWS.

The coding is actually duplicated ROWS, with opposite layouts, using DISABLE to display them correctly for each device.
[In the photo below, (desktop view) the greyed out section displays on mobile, while the *similar row* displays on desktop and tablet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNjYK.png)

---

Alternatively, there are some snippets people have written, which may or may not function properly- but are child-theme add-ins.

One such site that has information and the code is here:
https://www.fldtrace.com/better-faster-responsive-images-divi